# Is there any way to give permission to view a GitHub repo for an anonymous reviewer?

Tags: security, github, secret-key

I would like to share some material with a reviewer by embedding a link in my research proposal, but I do not like to make this repo public. Is there any way to do this by respecting his/her anonimity? Solutions based on platforms other than GitHub are also welcome.

I tried to read the description on the creation of a GitHub repo, but I did not find anything about this issue.

Comment: Hi Roland,
for my understanding, GitHub does not provide a way to give anonymous access to private repositories. In order to view a private repository, a user must be authenticated and authorized with the appropriate permissions.

Comment: @DomenicoMarino This was also my fear. Many thanks.